# sed using double quotes doesn't expand the variables

Tags: variables, sed, double-quotes

I'm trying to build a sh script, that would automatically replace a key word in .xml files with a string, the problem occures in sed expression, here is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
#STRINGS
  string[1]='Johny'
  string[2]='extern'
  string[3]="$(date +%Y_%m_%d-%H:%M:%S)"
  string[4]='0.0.Beta'
  string[5]='Velocity 64km/h'
  string[6]='deionduensis'
  string[7]='iehjnonduneo'
#STRING KEYS
  string_key[1]='Author'
  string_key[2]='Department'
  string_key[3]='Date'
  string_key[4]='Version' 
  string_key[5]='TITLE'
  string_key[6]='Variant1'
  string_key[7]='Variant2'
#  
  files=$(ls ./2VAR/ppt/slides/*xml ./2VAR/ppt/slides/_rels/*xml.rels ./2VAR/ppt/charts/*xml)
#
  for ii in '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7'; do
    for file in $files; do
    sed "s|\*$string_key[$ii]\*|$string[$ii]|g" $file > $file.tmp
    mv $file.tmp $file
    done
  done
```

The '*' before and after $string_key[$ii] are ok, they are surrounding the key words in .xml files.
The result is, nothing is replaced. I tried to replace the variables in sed with one of the string (string keys) and it seems to me, the problem is, the variable $string_key[$ii] won't be expanded, but I don't know why.. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

To reference an array member, use the following syntax:

```
${string_key[$ii]}
```

or

```
${string_key[ii]}
```

`$string_key[$ii]` is equivalent to `$string_key'['$ii']'`

Comment: @user3906722: Weird. Works for me. Did you fix **both** the arrays?

Comment: OK, It works now :), my mistake , thanks a lot choroba!

Comment: I did comment the 'mv $file.tmp $file' line and at the end checked the .tmp files at the end. What I didn't realized was, that the tmp files change each time the for $file cycle run:). Now it works fine, thanks again